# How to add an additional value to the key in the existing Javascript and how to populate it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an objects as

```
const ABC = {
    xxx: 50.00,
    yyy: 50.00,
    zzz: 60.00
}
```

In this 1st field is for Name, 2nd for price. How to add a new field for count (like `xxx: 50.00 2`).
Also how to pick that 3rd field. First field can be obtained by key. 2nd field is its value. How about the count field.
New to this,so kindly excuse in case this is an simple question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to store two fields under one key like this, but you can just store an array instead, where the first element is the name and the second element is the count:

```js
const ABC = {
    xxx: [50.00, 0],
    yyy: [50.00, 1],
    zzz: [60.00, 3]
};

ABC.xxx[1] = 2; // assign to count field
const [xxxPrice, xxxCount] = ABC.xxx;
console.log(xxxPrice, xxxCount);
```

Or, you could store an object:

```js
const ABC = {
    xxx: { price: 50.00, count: 0 },
    yyy: { price: 50.00, count: 1 },
    zzz: { price: 60.00, count: 3 }
};

ABC.xxx.count = 2; // assign to count field
const { price: xxxPrice, count: xxxCount } = ABC.xxx;
console.log(xxxPrice, xxxCount);
```

Comment: Perfect. And to get that object converted to above format, one can use this: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(ABC).map(([key, value], i)=>[key, {price: value[0], count: i}]))`

Comment: @gorak I think OP was referring to `count` as being a quantity of the item, rather than the index of the item, but the rest of it is good